Why touching just one source, make recompiles again the other untouched source file?
Just touching file mod1.c, make should just recompile that source file, produce its correspondent object file, mod1.o, and should not recompile mod2.c, because the object file mod2.o will be still completely up to date (mod2.c is, as untouched, yet older than mod2.o, so no need to recompile).
But I get the following behavior: 
(This is not a personal creation, is from a written example from a source on make [saying the text that one will witness how make knows that mod2.c is untouched and will not recompile it]).
Makefile
$ cat Makefile
SRC = mod1.c mod2.c main.c
OBJ = mod1.o mod2.o main.o
PROG = dbtest
            
$(PROG): $(OBJ)
        gcc $(OBJ) -o $(PROG)

$(OBJ): $(SRC) 


The problem:
$ make      
make: 'dbtest' is up to date.
                                                                                        
$ touch mod1.c
                                                                                        
$ make
cc    -c -o mod1.o mod1.c
cc    -c -o mod2.o mod2.c
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
gcc mod1.o mod2.o main.o -o dbtest

Files contents
$ cat mod1.c  
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
        printf("Hello ");
}
                                                                                        
$ cat mod2.c
#include <stdio.h>

void bar() {
        printf(“World\n”);
}


$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
void foo();
void bar();

int main (void) {
       foo();
       bar();

       return 0;
}


The problem comes from this line:
$(OBJ): $(SRC)

That expands to
mod1.o mod2.o main.o: mod1.c mod2.c main.c

which says that mod1.o, mod2.o, and main.o depend on mod1.c, mod2.c, and main.c, so that all three should be rebuilt if any of the source files change.
To get the behaviour you want, remove the line: Make will then use its built-in rules which say that a given .o file is built from its equivalent .c file if such a file exists.
